# How to get clang-format to allow single line lambdas with Allman indentation?

Tags: lambda, clang-format

I am working in a C++ codebase that uses `Allman` style brace wrapping. (Braces are placed on their own line.) Despite setting `AllowShortLambdasOnASingleLine` to `true`, `clang-format` still insists on breaking short lambdas onto two lines in a bizarre looking way.

`.clang-format`:

```
AllowShortLambdasOnASingleLine: true
BreakBeforeBraces: Allman
ColumnLimit: 0
IndentWidth: 4
Standard: c++17
```

`clang-format` output:

```
int main()
{
    auto shorter = []()
    { return 5; };

    auto longer = []()
    {
        int i = 5;
        return i;
    };
}
```

I tried fiddling with a `Custom` `BreakBeforeBraces` setup, but I get the exact same result.

```
AllowShortLambdasOnASingleLine: true
BraceWrapping:
  AfterFunction: true
  BeforeLambdaBody: true
BreakBeforeBraces: Custom
ColumnLimit: 0
Standard: c++17
IndentWidth: 4
```

Am I missing a setting? I can't imagine that anybody actually likes to see short lambdas on two lines like that.